# How do you remove and replace an NSTextAttachment in an NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, nstextattachment

I have a mutable attributed string which I have added an image text attachment to.

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attributedString = [_textField.attributedText mutableCopy];

NSMutableDictionary* dict = [_homeFeedCommentsViewController.inputData.array_extraElements objectAtIndex:0];

NSNumber* indexObject = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:attributedString.length];

[dict setObject:indexObject forKey:@"LocationIndex"];

[attributedString insertAttributedString:imageAsAttributedString atIndex:attributedString.length];
```

How do i now get at that text attachment & replace it with a string at the location where the image is supposed to be located in the body of the text?

Comment: What about using `replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply tell the text storage you updated the attributes for the range of your corresponding attachment character:

```
textStorage.edited([.EditedAttributes], range: range, changeInLength: 0)
```